# How far from the computer screen is it recommended to sit?

Tags: display, ergonomics, work-environment

I would like to know if there is any recommendations about how far from the computer screen it is good (healthy) to sit when I work in front of the computer long days. In an ergonomic perspective.

Comment: For those voting to close as off-topic, I do find this a useful topic and made it Community Wiki since I don't expect anyone to post scientific evidence for the correct postion and location behind a computer ;-)

Comment: @Ivo: very similar to (possible duplicate of) http://superuser.com/questions/133639/what-is-the-most-optimal-viewing-distance-for-different-resolutions

Comment: @quack: Meeh I should just create one CW question about ergonomics and put everything in it. Everyone asks the same in a slightly different manner :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This page](http://ergo.human.cornell.edu/ergoguide.html) which turned up on a search for "ideal distance from computer monitor" states:

> **viewing distance** - the monitor should be at a comfortable horizontal distance for viewing, which usually is around an arms length (sit back in your chair and raise your arm and your fingers should touch the screen). At this distance you should be able to see the viewing area of the monitor without making head movements. If text looks too small then either use a larger font or magnify the screen image in the software rather than sitting closer to the monitor.

Which isn't definitive, but does raise the good point about adjusting the screen resolution and/or font sizes rather than moving closer to (or further from) the screen.

Answer (score 5):

I've asked the [same question](https://superuser.com/questions/133639/what-is-the-most-optimal-viewing-distance-for-different-resolutions-or-sizes-mo) before. It appears the "one arm rule" to be in place. However I tend to disagree for larger displays like 20+". [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimum_HDTV_viewing_distance) also has a nice article about calculating viewing angles, distances and field of view.

And my own adapted rule for screens above 14" is: distance = 1.5 * screen diagonal.

Comment: That would put me 40" away from my 27" Dell! No way, that's too far.

Comment: I'd actually prefer more of an overview of my 27" monitor, so _at least_ 1m away from it. Otherwise, I find it a bit difficult to change focus from one side to another

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice visual representation of guidelines:
[image]

This seems to agree with some of the other answers here, but some people find a visual easier to grok.

Source: https://stari.co/tv-monitor-viewing-distance-calculator

Comment: This is a nice graph, but distance should be based on screen size (AKA field of view) and screen brightness, not resolution.  This looks like it is designed to justify 4k displays rather than to provide any real insight.

Comment: @MobyDisk it does show the screen size but you may well be right about resolution vs. brightness.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the eye sight of the person. Some feel comfort sitting closer to the screen. While for some it will be to sit far.

But in normal case (with small monitor) a minimum of `one arm distance` (`30 cm`) is to be between our eyes and the monitor.

(The distance should increase as the height of the monitor increase)

Comment: I tend to agree with the arm's length suggestion, but the average adult arm is a *lot* longer than 30 cm (which is only 1' or 12"). My arms are at least double that.

Answer (score -5):

I think that is is best to sit pretty close to the computer, i sit about 10-15cm away from the monitor otherwise my eyes get pretty sore, and everything is blury. My eyesight is so-so, but hasnt got worse in a few years. Most of my friends sit like this too, seems to be the best distance on a 17" screen. I usually go back about 1cm for each inch bigger

Comment: You're in urgent need of seeing the eye-doctor and may need special eyeglasses for working with computer screens. You may also expose yourself to excessive electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: Hey Harrymc. I actully have glasses for distance but dont wear them very often. I find it most comfortable to sit close to the screen as do many others. Cheers

Comment: This is terrible advice. You should wear your glasses when you're on the computer instead of frying your eyes.